# git apply fails with error: while searching for

Tags: git

When running `git apply --check -v` on a patch I have created, I receive several `error: while searching for: ...` errors. But the offending lines are definitely present in the files affected (the file paths are also correct).

Unfortunately I cannot post the patch here. Has someone experienced something similar before and can tell me what might cause this?

Comment: Some idea? I'm stuck, my patch is outdated. Is there some easy way to "resolve conflicts" of my patch?